# IE caching ajax request does not execute javascript function

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, caching, browser

I have a javascript file loading via jQuery.getScript on the client and I'm setting cache-control headers with 1hr browser caching on the server side. It looks like IE caches ajax requests and the functions present in the file do not execute in IE. Does setting false in the getScript call override the cache-control headers of 1hr set from the server side?

```
var jsCache = true;
    if($.browser.msie){
        jsCache = false;
    }
        if(!initialized){

            $.getScript('thatjsfileurl', function() { 
             $("#welcome").pluginInit({
                start:'newPage'
             });  
             initialized = true;
            },jsCache);
        }
```

Note: There is also Akamai in place, so can't set the browser detection code on the servlet side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the answered by myself by testing the above code I posted. The server side header variables like cache-control: 1hr etc are overridden by the browser when we set the variable to cache is set to false. Everytime the IE browser fetches a new copy from the server when the cache is set to false.

```
var jsCache = true;
    if($.browser.msie){
        jsCache = false;
    }
        if(!initialized){

            $.getScript('thatjsfileurl', function() { 
             $("#welcome").pluginInit({
                start:'newPage'
             });  
             initialized = true;
            },jsCache);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [jQuery doc for getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), there is no cache setting argument for the `getScript()` call so you aren't doing anything with your jsCache variable.

You can add a timestamp number into the URL and bypass any IE caching.

```
    if(!initialized) {
        $.getScript("thatjsfileurl" + "?now=" + new Date().getTime(), function() { 
            $("#welcome").pluginInit({
               start:'newPage'
            });  
            initialized = true;
        });
    }
```